# Использую aiogram3.0 чтоб отправить на почту фото. Появляется ошибка file.save(memf, "JPEG") AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'save' help

Tags: python-3.x, smtp, io, pil, aiogram-3.x

```
import asyncio
from config import dop_password, token, email, password
import logging
import sys
from nicknames import white_list
import os
from os import getenv
from typing import Any, Dict
from aiogram import types
from aiogram import Bot, Dispatcher, F, Router, html
from aiogram.filters import Command
from aiogram.fsm.context import FSMContext
from aiogram.fsm.state import State, StatesGroup
from email.mime.multipart import MIMEMultipart
from email.mime.text import MIMEText
import smtplib
from aiogram.methods.get_file import GetFile
from PIL import Image
import io

@form_router.message(Form.stage8)
async def process_name(message: Message, state: FSMContext) -> None:
    kb = [[
        types.KeyboardButton(text="/start")
    ]]
    keyboard = types.ReplyKeyboardMarkup(keyboard=kb, resize_keyboard=True)
    memf = io.StringIO()
    file = message.document.file_id
    file.save(memf, "JPEG")
    file.document.file_id = MIMEImage(memf.getvalue())
    data = await state.get_data()
    theme = data.get('stage1')
    author = data.get('stage2')
    problem = data.get('stage3')
    place = data.get('stage4')
    contacts = data.get('stage5')
    number = data.get('stage6')
    addr_from = email
    addr_to = 'email'
    mgs = MIMEMultipart()
    mgs['From'] = addr_from
    mgs['To'] = addr_to
    mgs['Subject'] = f'{theme}'
    body = (f'''
    Описание: {problem}
    Автор заявки: {author}
    Кабинет: {place}
    Контакты для обратной связи: {contacts}
    Инвентаризационный номер устройства: {number}
    ''')
    mgs.attach(MIMEText(body, 'plain'))
    mgs.attach(file)
    smtpObj = smtplib.SMTP('smtp.mail.ru', 587)
    smtpObj.starttls()
    smtpObj.login(addr_from, dop_password)
    smtpObj.send_message(mgs)
    smtpObj.quit()
    await state.clear()
    await message.answer("Ваша заявка успешно отправлена!\nДля написания новой 
    заявки нажмите кнопку /start", reply_markup=keyboard)
```

Comment: Внимательней на строчке file=